# Voltage protection with relay and Zener

Tags: relay, zener, circuit-protection

I'm having a hard time finding a good way to protect a radio module if the voltage regulator fails and injects the battery's input voltage. The module is expensive, so I would like to protect it from voltage above 3.6V.

The module works in 3.3V up to 3.6V, higher voltage can burn it.

The circuit that I thought would solve my problem:

[image]

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. The over-volt condition may well over-drive the relay, plus the relay's probably too slow to act before said damage is done. You can use a precision crowbar across the rail and a fuse in the supply to cut the crowbarred power but I've no time to draw such a thing, hence this comment and not an answer. But that's based on a shaky premise: why would the regulator reliability be so low that you'd have to add such protection? RF module's might have similar reliability to regulator anyway, so either could fail. Best spend money on a decent regulator with enough margin.

Comment: What's the purpose of the relay? You seem to have used the wrong schematic symbol, but apart from that it just looks like "dumb copper". Is it there for polarity protection only? The same can be achieved much cheaper with a MOSFET.

Comment: Also what's the meaning of "400Mah"? Mega acceleration hours don't make any sense. Neither does milliamperehours.

Answer (score 1):

The idea looks to be correct but it doesn't look like you will be supplying the relay enough voltage to activate. So you need to add a stage there. The zener will supply a reference voltage to a comparator or something similar. The output of the comparator will then operate the relay ( possibly off a separate supply ). You might need to add a driver for the comparator to supply enough current for the relay to operate. However, a relay is a bit of clunky solution. It is mechanical, high failure device of its own, maybe too slow to react to protect your circuit. Why not replace the relay with a MOSFET or BJT switch? Also, transients can be removed with some bypass capacitors on your 3.3V regulator.

Comment: "but it doesn't look like you will be supplying the relay enough voltage to activate" Why not? It's 3.6V zener and the coil is rated at 3V.

Comment: @Lundin If it's a 3V relay and a 3.6V zener, then the relay won't reliably operate unless the voltage exceeds 6.6V.  That's much too high for your module.

Comment: @SimonB This answer claims that the coil voltage is too low. The problem is rather too high voltage across the contacts. Also zener voltage means that it starts to conduct at that voltage, so if you go above 3.6V you'll supply the coil.

Comment: SimonB is correct because your zener is misplaced. The zener should be at the bottom and the resistor above. However, it still won't work for other reasons. You need a driver circuit between the zener and coil or the coil will short the zener. Also, the IV curve of a zener is not sharp enough to use like this for such critically small voltage changes.

Answer (score 1):

A mechanical relay will be way too slow to protect electronics.

You could add a regulator in front of the 3.3V regulator, preferably a switching regulator (for efficiency, though noise might be an issue), and then there would have to be two failures for the module to see the input voltage. Make sure the second regulator has adequate protection and rating to not fail if fed 12V directly (could be thermal overload protection and adequate input voltage/SOA rating).

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work. If the voltage regulator failed and did output 12V, the RF module will be damaged by 12V before the relay coil actuates and disconnects 12V from RF module input.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup reacts far away from 3v6 voltage. Btw, the the relay is too slow to protect sensitive load.

The schematic below should works better.
(The U1 is still LM60430, I could not find a model in library, also the input diode)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2vXLK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>